# Hiveserver2 does not start after installing HDP 2.6.4.0-91 using cloudbreak on AWS

Tags: hive, ambari, cloudbreak

Hiveserver2 does not start after installing HDP 2.6.4.0-91 using cloudbreak on AWS.

Start the hiveserver2 in the Ambari UI and check the contents of `/var/log/hive/hiveserver2.log`.

Below is the error log.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

### Contents of hiveserver2.log

```
2018-03-08 04:41:53,345 WARN [main-EventThread]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:process(343)) - This instance of HiveServer2 has been removed from the list of server instances available for dynamic service discovery. The last client session has ended - will shutdown now.
2018-03-08 04:41:53,347 INFO [main]: zookeeper.ZooKeeper (ZooKeeper.java:close(684)) - Session: 0x16203aad5af0040 closed
2018-03-08 04:41:53,347 INFO [main]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:removeServerInstanceFromZooKeeper(361)) - Server instance removed from ZooKeeper.
2018-03-08 04:41:53,348 INFO [main-EventThread]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:stop(405)) - Shutting down HiveServer2
2018-03-08 04:41:53,348 INFO [main-EventThread]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:removeServerInstanceFromZooKeeper(361)) - Server instance removed from ZooKeeper.
2018-03-08 04:41:53,348 INFO [main-EventThread]: zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:run(524)) - EventThread shut down
2018-03-08 04:41:53,348 WARN [main]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:startHiveServer2(508)) - Error starting HiveServer2 on attempt 1, will retry in 60 seconds
org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning: TezSession has already shutdown. Application application_1520480101488_0046 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1520480101488_0046_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://ip-10-0-91-7.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1520480101488_0046 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: ExitCodeException exitCode=2: tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Skipping to next header

gzip: /hadoopfs/fs1/yarn/nodemanager/filecache/60_tmp/tmp_tez.tar.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.waitTillReady(TezClient.java:699)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:218)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionPoolManager.startPool(TezSessionPoolManager.java:76)
at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.startHiveServer2(HiveServer2.java:488)
at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.access$700(HiveServer2.java:87)
at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2$StartOptionExecutor.execute(HiveServer2.java:720)
at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.main(HiveServer2.java:593)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with HDP on AWS. FYI, In my case the issue was with HDP version **2.6.4.5-2**. I'm going to show how I fixed using this version because it is the latest at this time.

As the error log shows the problem is with **tez.tar.gz** that **is corrupted** then YARN is unable to decompress it in the YARN container.

This `tez.tar.gz` file is copied from the `hdfs:///hdp/apps/<hdp_version>/tez/tez.tar.gz`.

To reproduce the error and confirm that this file is corrupted, you can run the following command:

```
 sudo su 
 su hdfs
 hdfs dfs -get /hdp/apps/2.6.4.5-2/tez.tar.gz
 tar -xvzf tez.tar.gz
```

You will get the following error:

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

The fix is pretty simple, you must just replace the HDFS file with the one that you have on your local file-system running the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -rm /hdp/apps/2.6.4.5-2/tez/tez.tar.gz
hdfs dfs -put /usr/hdp/current/tez-client/lib/tez.tar.gz /hdp/apps/2.6.4.5-2/tez/tez.tar.gz
```

Now **restart Hive Server 2** service and done!

**NOTE:** If something similar happens with other services you can do the same thing. Please check the following link that has more details: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/30096/foxing-broken-targz-and-jar-files-in-hdp-24.html

Hope this helps!